# Is it necessary to free the file pointer when working with a file in the C language?

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm studying files in C and I was curious if it's necessary to use the `free()` function in the file type pointer, if not, I'd like an explanation.

```
    FILE *p;
```

Since `p` is a pointer shouldn't it be free anyway?

Comment: You never should free a file pointer. Rule of thumb: free anything that has been obained via `malloc`/`calloc` and `realloc`, and nothing else.

Comment: ... including indirectly, by a function whose documentation says so, such as POSIX `strdup()`.

Comment: The rule is *not*, "If it's a pointer, you need to free it."  If you say `int i; int *ip = &i;`, that's not a pointer you need to free, either.

Answer (score 8):

The primary 'allocator' for file streams (`FILE *`) is [`fopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) (though there are some others<sup>1</sup>).

The primary 'deallocator' for file streams is [`fclose()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fclose.html)<sup>2</sup>.

You should not use [`free()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html) to attempt to release a file stream.  You should only free memory allocated 'as if' with `malloc()` or its relatives.  It is important to know when you create/access a resource in your program, what is the correct way to release that resource.  The manual pages will tell you.

---

<sup>1</sup> [`freopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html), [`fdopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html), [`fmemopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html),
[`popen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html).

<sup>2</sup> [`pclose()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pclose.html).  Note that file streams created with `popen()` should be released with `pclose()`, not `fclose()`.